# Tesseract and Tess4J

Tags: tesseract

I have a question regarding the tesseract training.
I am currently using Tess4J in order to integrate tesseract within my java program.
Reading on the tesseract wiki page on tesseract training (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3), one is able to train tesseract using training images with various combinations and fonts.

Is it possible for me to have just a "normal" tesseract 3.02 (windows or unix) installation constructing these lang.traineddata files, and afterwards just include this in my tessdata folder utilized by my Tess4J wrapper from my java program. Or is the Tess4J limitied to the included language data for English, and sample images that are bundled with the program?

If so, is it possible to include these in to my Tess4J build in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is just a wrapper of Tesseract OCR engine, it accepts any standard issue or custom traineddata files. You can find the standard traineddata at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata.